# See records not available for all visual.

Tags: powerbi-embedded

In my Power BI desktop I  see "See Records" under Modelling greyed out for some visuals...Like Line and Stacked Column.

However when I change visual to say Clustered column chart "See records" is enabled.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Limitations**

There are a few limitations to consider when using See Data or See Records:

Only the following visual types are supported:

- Bar
- Column
- Map
- Tree Map
- Filled Map
- Pie
- Donut
- Funnel

You can't use See Records when your visual uses a calculated measure.

From this site (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-see-data-see-records/)

Comment: Not sure why it can't be done for all visuals. Thanks for the link